# std::thread in a loop results in incorrect results

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I am working on a program that runs in a for loop. Since the arguments and outputs for each call is unique I though I could parallelize the calls within the loop. However this doesn't work correctly. Following is an example program that illustrates this issue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

void subProg1(int& ii, double& emod, double& prat);
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  int imax = 4;
  int ii;
  double emod[4];
  double prat[4];

  std::thread threadpointer[4];

  emod[0] = 10;
  emod[1] = 20;
  emod[2] = 30;
  emod[3] = 40;

  prat[0] = 0.1;
  prat[1] = 0.2;
  prat[2] = 0.3;
  prat[3] = 0.4;


  for (ii=0;ii<imax;ii++) {
    cout<<" In main Program " <<endl;
    cout<<" count = : "<<ii<<" emod = : "<<emod[ii]<<" pRat = : "<<prat[ii]<<endl;
    threadpointer[ii] = std::thread(subProg1,ref(ii),ref(emod[ii]),ref(prat[ii]));
    //threadpointer[ii].join();
  }

  for (ii=0;ii<imax;ii++) {
    threadpointer[ii].join();
  }
    

}

void subProg1(int& ii, double& emod, double& prat)
{
   cout <<" In SubProgram "<<endl;
   cout<<" count = : "<<ii<<" emod = : "<<emod<<" pRat = : "<<prat<<endl;
}
```

The output of this run is as follows

```
 In main Program
 count = : 0 emod = : 10 pRat = : 0.1
 In SubProgram
 In main Program
 count = : 1 emod = :  count = : 1 emod = : 20 pRat = : 0.2
10 pRat = : 0.1
 In SubProgram
 In main Program
 count = : 2 emod = : 20 pRat = : 0.2
 count = : 2 emod = : 30 pRat = : 0.3
 In SubProgram
 In main Program
 count = : 3 emod = : 40 pRat = : 0.4
 count = : 3 emod = : 30 pRat = :  In SubProgram
 count = : 2 emod = : 40 pRat = : 0.4
0.3
```

I do understand the calls will be out of sync. However the index and the values of emod and prat corresponding to that index don't match either. The correct values should be

```
count = :0 emod = : 10 pRat = :0.1
count = :1 emod = : 20 pRat = :0.2
count = :2 emod = : 30 pRat = :0.3
count = :3 emod = : 40 pRat = :0.4
```

Wondering what I am missing. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Capture `ii` by value, otherwise if `ii` captured by reference, it is affected by `++` in for loop.

Comment: As @rafix07 says, you have a race condition in your code as all the created threads try to access `ii` at the same time the `for` loop is modifying it.

Comment: Thank you. that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont pass the counter by reference, as when it increments in main, it will increment in the thread as well. Pass it by value.

```
void subProg1(int ii, double& emod, double& prat);
```